# In production, contact form: ActionMailer does not send email. ArgumentError (At least one recipient (To, Cc or Bcc) is required to send a message)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, production-environment

I created simple contact form (similar to: http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/) and in my development, it works fine (using letter opener)
but in my production, it does not send the mail.
I searched some solutions but I could not find solution.
Why not sending email even though **to:** is defined in `models/mailers/contact_mailer.rb` ?
in heroku logs the parameters looked fine but it could not find `to:` ... Please help me.

**entire repo**
https://github.com/yhagio/yhagio

**actual contact form**
http://yhagio.herokuapp.com/contact

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "yhagio.herokuapp.com" }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :domain               => 'yhagio.herokuapp.com',
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
  :password             => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
}
```

**models/mailers/contact_mailer.rb**

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: ENV['MYGMAIL']

  def contact_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail from: message.email, subject: message.subject
  end
end
```

**message.rb**

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  validates_presence_of :subject, :body, :name
  validates :email,  presence: true, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i  }

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :body, :subject

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

**contact_mailer.rb**

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      ContactMailer.contact_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:success] = "Message was successfully sent."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

**heroku logs**

```
app[web.1]: Started POST "/contact" for 173.176.46.53 at 2013-07-22 23:14:50 +0000
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"czYfbExDwXdHvzKP7fa3LMV50CbucTGwxwV/sZ22E/c=", "message"=>{"name"=>"test", "email"=>"test@test.com", "subject"=>"hello", "body"=>"https://github.com/yhagio/yhagio/commit/c8a09d769df43a58f82959fc1e72e3c88b79821d"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
Processing by ContactController#create as HTML
Rendered contact_mailer/contact_message.html.haml (2.4ms)
at=info method=POST path=/contact host=yhagio.herokuapp.com fwd="173.176.46.53" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=76ms status=500 bytes=643
Sent mail to  (10ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms
app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:11:in `create'
ArgumentError (At least one recipient (To, Cc or Bcc) is required to send a message):
```

**UPDATE: July 24**

I tried Mailgun as modified in **config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
  :domain         => 'yhagio.herokuapp.com',
  :port           => 587, 
  :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
  :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the domain should be gmail.com instead of yhagio.herokuapp.com.

Comment: I tried `:domain => 'gmail.com',` and also `:domain => ENV['MYGMAIL'],` but neither works.

Comment: Since it's working in dev mode, you should try it with services like Mailgun or Mandrill. Gmail often has this kind of problems.

Comment: Yes, but I also tried Mailgun (I updated the code above) but when I checked `heroku logs`, it is same result and not sending email to my email.

Comment: But I use my default **to:** for ActionMailer is still my own gmail, which should not be problem unless I use gmail for **from:**, right?

Comment: The Error log tells us that it doesn't get a value for "to:". Have you double-checked your input for ENV['MYGMAIL']? Also try to include it in the contact_message action instead of "default to:"

Comment: Finally it worked, I put actual email instead of ENV['MYGMAIL'] in `default to:` and add `:to` in `contact_message` method as you suggested. Thanks @KentTucky